# After expo eject : Task 'installDebug' not found in root project 'android'

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I would like to build my app without sending the source on Expo server.

So, I ejected my application of Expo with ExpoKit.

I use the command `expo eject`, the result is a success.

I start the app with `react-native run-android` and I have an error. The problem has been solved by adding `gradlew.bat` to the directory `android`. By default, it is missing with `expo eject`.

So I start the app again, build begin but I have a second error :

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Task 'installDebug' not found in root project 'android'.

* Try:
Run gradlew tasks to get a list of available tasks. Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

In directory `android` I use this command `gradlew tasks` and I have that :

```
...
Install tasks
-------------
installDevKernelDebug - Installs the DebugDevKernel build.
installDevKernelDebugAndroidTest - Installs the android (on device) tests for the DevKernelDebug build.
installProdKernelDebug - Installs the DebugProdKernel build.
installProdKernelDebugAndroidTest - Installs the android (on device) tests for the ProdKernelDebug build.
uninstallAll - Uninstall all applications.
uninstallDevKernelDebug - Uninstalls the DebugDevKernel build.
uninstallDevKernelDebugAndroidTest - Uninstalls the android (on device) tests for the DevKernelDebug build.
uninstallDevKernelRelease - Uninstalls the ReleaseDevKernel build.
uninstallProdKernelDebug - Uninstalls the DebugProdKernel build.
uninstallProdKernelDebugAndroidTest - Uninstalls the android (on device) tests for the ProdKernelDebug build.
uninstallProdKernelRelease - Uninstalls the ReleaseProdKernel build.
...
```

When I create a react-native application I don't have this problem.

```
Install tasks
-------------
installDebug - Installs the Debug build.
installDebugAndroidTest - Installs the android (on device) tests for the Debug build.
uninstallAll - Uninstall all applications.
uninstallDebug - Uninstalls the Debug build.
uninstallDebugAndroidTest - Uninstalls the android (on device) tests for the Debug build.
uninstallRelease - Uninstalls the Release build.
```

I except the final line Build success or another error which would mean that I am unlocked!

Answer (score 0):

#### Step 1 :

Don't use `react-native run-android`.

#### Step 2 :

If you are using Windows and you don't have the file `gradlew.bat` (but only gradlew), download it [from here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/facebook/react-native/92073770589abc68654e6f1abdd232b45241b181/template/android/gradlew.bat) or copy it from an another react-native project.

#### Step 3 :

In directory /android execute the command `gradlew tasks` or `gradlew.bat tasks` if you are on Windows.

Check the commands that can be used in Install tasks

```
Install tasks
-------------
installDevKernelDebug - Installs the DebugDevKernel build.
installDevKernelDebugAndroidTest - Installs the android (on device) tests for the DevKernelDebug build.
installProdKernelDebug - Installs the DebugProdKernel build.
installProdKernelDebugAndroidTest - Installs the android (on device) tests for the ProdKernelDebug build.
uninstallAll - Uninstall all applications.
uninstallDevKernelDebug - Uninstalls the DebugDevKernel build.
uninstallDevKernelDebugAndroidTest - Uninstalls the android (on device) tests for the DevKernelDebug build.
uninstallDevKernelRelease - Uninstalls the ReleaseDevKernel build.
uninstallProdKernelDebug - Uninstalls the DebugProdKernel build.
uninstallProdKernelDebugAndroidTest - Uninstalls the android (on device) tests for the ProdKernelDebug build.
uninstallProdKernelRelease - Uninstalls the ReleaseProdKernel build.
Use the command gradlew installDevKernelDebug.
```

#### Step 4 :

If you are using react-native, go in the root directory and run `npm start` or `expo start` if you are using expo.
In the browser go to http://localhost:19002 (or the port it says on your console).

Select the local connection and recover the value like
expXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX://127.0.0.1:19000.

Check the file on `.\android\app\src\main\java\host\exp\exponent\generated\DetachBuildConstants.java` and copy the value in `DEVELOPMENT_URL` variable.

#### Step 5 :

Exit Metro Bundler with CTRL+C on the console.

#### Step 6 :

Run `cd android` to enter ./android/ directory

#### Step 7 :

Run `gradlew installDevKernelDebug` or other task you listed on **Step 3**.

I found most of these directions on this thread: https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/4097